# Is it possible to travel from Mai Chau to Son La by motorbike?

Tags: road-trips, vietnam, motorcycles

I have a question that is very similar ["Hanoi to Mai Chau by motorbike"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57683/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-hanoi-to-mai-chau-by-motorbike) but for **Mai Chau** to **Son La**.

A friend and I plan to go from [Mai Chau](https://goo.gl/maps/dCNP8oM7tvj) to [Son La](https://goo.gl/maps/ar2ka4AZZ6n) by motorbike (around 190km). Each of us will drive a **Honda Win 110cc**. As for the other related question I have only found a couple of articles mentioning this route so I'd just like to get feedback from more travellers.

The **QL6 national road** seems to be the simplest way to do this journey, however I wonder if there is more convenient route (e.g. less traffic, or better scenery)?

[image: Mai Chau to Son La]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

#### Resources

http://www.tripline.net/trip/North_Vietnam_Motorcycle_Tours_Ride_Hanoi_Mai_Chau_Son_La_Lai_Chau_Sapa_Yen_Bai_(6_days)-0172323170211005B6CFFFFE281DBD9A

http://hanoieasyrider.com/vietnam-motorcycle-tours/motorcycle-tours-hanoi-mai-chau-son-la-dien-bien-phu-sa-pa-hanoi-8-days/s25

Comment: What was your eventual route?

Comment: I answered my own question. I did not put much details as I did this a while ago now & could not remember much. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my input **after doing it myself**.

It's completely doable, the ride is just fine.

It takes a total of around **5h**: about 4h ride, plus 1h for stops on the way (going to toilet & taking pics).

I took the **QL6 national road**.