# Is it possible to travel from Son La to Dien Bien Phu by motorbike?

Tags: road-trips, vietnam, motorcycles

I have a question that is very similar to ["Hanoi to Mai Chau by motorbike"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57683/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-hanoi-to-mai-chau-by-motorbike) & ["Mai Chau to Son La by motorbike"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57716/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-mai-chau-to-son-la-by-motorbike) but for **Son La** to **Dien Bien Phu**.

A friend and I plan to go from [Son La](https://goo.gl/maps/C5GgZpU3exr) to [Dien Bien Phu](https://goo.gl/maps/Y9svc4uLqck) by motorbike (around 150km). Each of us will drive a **Honda Win 110cc**. As for the other related questions I have only found a couple of articles mentioning this route so I'd just like to get feedback from more travellers.

The **QL6 national road** followed by the **Quốc lộ 279 national road** seem to be the simplest way to do this journey, however I wonder if there is more convenient route (e.g. less traffic, or better scenery)?

[image: Son La to Dien Bien Phu]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

#### Resources

http://hanoieasyrider.com/vietnam-motorcycle-tours/motorcycle-tours-hanoi-mai-chau-son-la-dien-bien-phu-sa-pa-hanoi-8-days/s25

http://www.fodors.com/community/asia/vietnam-motorcycle-itinerary-feedback-pleeease.cfm

Comment: Which route did you end up taking?

Comment: See my reply as an answer

Comment: @JonathanReez you probably are interested in reading this next: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61735/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-dien-bien-phu-to-lai-ch%C3%A2u-by-motorbike

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking the **QL6 national road** followed by the **Quốc lộ 279 national road**.

It took around 5h in total.

---

#### Other resources

I bumped into a [Spanish blog having an article about the Son La to Dien Bien Phu route](http://www.conmochila.com/etapa-4-son-la-dien-bien-phu-ruta-en-moto-por-vietnam). The nice part is, they shared the GPS tracking for the journey at the bottom of the article. You can also directly find this ["Son La to Dien Bien Phu" GPS track on Wikiloc](http://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/view.do?id=8415193).