# Is it possible to travel from Dien Bien Phu to Lai Châu by motorbike?

Tags: road-trips, vietnam, motorcycles

I have a question that is very similar to ["Hanoi to Mai Chau by motorbike"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57683/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-hanoi-to-mai-chau-by-motorbike), ["Mai Chau to Son La by motorbike"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57716/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-mai-chau-to-son-la-by-motorbike) & ["Son La to Dien Bien Phu by motorbike"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/is-it-possible-to-travel-from-son-la-to-dien-bien-phu-by-motorbike) but for **Son La** to **Dien Bien Phu**.

A friend and I plan to go from [Dien Bien Phu](https://goo.gl/maps/Y9svc4uLqck) to [Lai Châu](https://goo.gl/maps/RnZMwucEvZN2) by motorbike (around 200km). Each of us will drive a **Honda Win 110cc**. As for the other related questions I have only found a couple of articles mentioning this route so I'd just like to get feedback from more travellers.

The **QL12 national road** followed by the **QL4D national road** seem to be the simplest way to do this journey, however I wonder if there is more convenient route (e.g. less traffic, or better scenery)?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up taking the **QL12 national road** followed by the **QL4D national road** as researched before.

I was hoping to do that journey by bus by putting the motorbike in the bus (yes they do it usually!) & get some rest in the bus. But they did not want to do it, so had to ride again & for a tougher ride this time.

The road was really bad. It was very neglected compared to the other roads I took before (Hanoi to Mai Chai to Son La to Dien Bien Phu). From what I remember, maybe 50% of the journey was terrible (narrow & many times very damaged). This could get a little scary in some places, so ride carefully.

I think it took a total of **6h** (with 1h break).

Lai Châu is a very funny/strange place. It has epic avenues, it is very spread out & has big buildings (governmental I guess) but there is not many people who seem to actually live there. A place of interest if you want to see the weird side of Communism in Vietnam I suppose.

---

#### Other resources

I bumped into a [Spanish blog having an article about the "Dien Bien Phu to Lai Châu" route](http://www.conmochila.com/etapa-6-dien-bien-phu-lai-chau-ruta-en-moto-por-vietnam). The nice part is, they shared the GPS tracking for the journey at the bottom of the article. You can also directly find this ["Dien Bien Phu to Lai Châu"" GPS track on Wikiloc](http://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/view.do?id=8426018).